# How to play animation before destroying the GameObject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I followed this [tip](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/475681/can-someone-show-me-how-to-play-a-death-animation.html), however I adapted it for my C# script. My death animation does not play on death. Why is that?

I already attached the animation to the script (to play when enemy health is 0).
[image]

Here is my code

```
public class EnemyHealthManager : MonoBehaviour {

    ... 

    private Animator fireAnimator;
    public AnimationClip fireDeathAnimation;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start() {
        currentHealth = maxHealth;
        fireAnimator = GetComponent<Animator> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        if (currentHealth <= 0)
        {

            fireAnimator.Play(fireDeathAnimation.name); //play Fire_Death animation on death
            Destroy(gameObject, 1.0f);  //dies after 1.0f seconds so that death animation can play
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It's more likely due to the fact that OP is calling fireAnimator.Play() every frame...

Comment: you're calling your animator and Destroy every single frame. Make sure it only gets called once

Comment: @Mars thanks that worked!